# Error While Editing XHTML Files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, xhtml

Whenever I try to edit an xhtml file in eclipse, it shows an internal error:

An internal error occured during "Processing variables for ...xhtml"
Could not initialize class org.apache.myfaces.shared.config.MyfacesConfig

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.myfaces.shared.config.MyfacesConfig
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelet.DTFacesConfigurator.configureApplication(DTFacesConfigurator.java:683)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelet.DTFacesConfigurator.configure(DTFacesConfigurator.java:414)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelet.FaceletCompilerConfigurator.configure(FaceletCompilerConfigurator.java:118)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelet.FaceletCompilerConfigurator.configure(FaceletCompilerConfigurator.java:97)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelets.OepeFaceletCompiler.createConfig(OepeFaceletCompiler.java:113)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelets.OepeFaceletCompiler.compile(OepeFaceletCompiler.java:78)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelets.FaceletCompileUtil.ensureContext(FaceletCompileUtil.java:35)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.dependency.discovery.FaceletDiscoveryParticipant.discover(FaceletDiscoveryParticipant.java:267)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.dependency.discovery.FaceletDiscoveryParticipant.discoverFromExistingModel(FaceletDiscoveryParticipant.java:361)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.application.common.services.variables.VariablesController$DocumentRediscoveryJob.runAfterCommands(VariablesController.java:746)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.concurrency.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:73)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: `oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.*` in stack trace suggests that you're using Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) plugin (and that it has a bug). Have you tried updating it? Have you tried opening the XHTML file in a different editor via rightclick, *Open With*?

Comment: I tried to update it, it didn't help. If I open in a different editor (for example in the html editor) it works perfectly.

Comment: did you tried another eclipse version, or re download the same version

Comment: The missing class is in https://myfaces.apache.org/ — putting this in the $ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins directory could potentially help

Comment: Shouldn't be an Eclipse bug. This is a bug in the OEPE plugin. It seems to have an hardcoded dependency on MyFaces. The answer would be: 1) Try a newer OEPE version, if any. Or 2) Report it as a bug to OEPE guys. Or 3) Drop it altogether and use another JSF2 capable plugin, e.g. JBoss Tools.

Comment: @BalusC can you tell me how to use JBoss Tools? I have installed JBTools, but the same error occurs everytime.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All [x-friends](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html) directives in the manifest file referenced to a wrong bundle.

Fix for the most recent version of OEPE (12.1.3.3.1):

1. Replace META-INF\MANIFEST.MF in plugins\oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelet_7.3.3.201412231459.jar with [this](https://github.com/palek/oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.facelet/blob/master/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF).
2. Restart eclipse

---

Comment: What did you change in that fixed MANIFEST.MF?